# Is it possible to solve for the resistance of R3 in this question, without knowing the total current of the circuit beforehand?

Tags: resistance, schematics, diagram

P.S. I'm not asking for the actual answer, I just need to know how to, so clues or reminders regarding the fundamentals would be fine by me[image]

Comment: yes, it looks like the value of current flowing through the circuit is missing

Comment: Is it possible that the red arrow had a current value marked next to it?

Comment: Surely you must have some other details about this circuit. Otherwise you have a system of 3 variables with 2 unknowns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current was indeed missing from the given values. The H.S. Physics teacher who made this question admitted that he didn't know what he was doing when making these questions.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew said, you have a system of single equation with two variables. If you would like to act smartypants to your teacher you could give him the following answer:

Mathematically it is solvable, the drawback is that there are infinitely many solutions :D.